# have edit permissions in your admob account

Tags: admob, adsense

Am trying to manage consent with funding choices with google admob but am getting this error->You need permission
To create a Funding Choices account, you need to have "edit" permissions in your AdMob or Ad Manager account.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a common issue at the moment. See https://support.google.com/admanager/thread/106454804?hl=en. I am one of the upvotes.

Comment: Ok thanks let me check

Comment: Thanks for adding the link back to this post. Still no luck, but hopefully soon. Surely there is a lot of demand starting up this week for it.

Comment: Imagine I had been paid for adding google ads but this the last thing to add so that ads can work.

Comment: Same issue here. Hope Google cleans this up soon.

Comment: It's past weeks now and no response from google. Or it's this corona thing

Comment: It seems this has now been fixed.

Comment: Yeah it's fixed. Happy Earnings.